# Flutter remove partial border between tab and tabview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How to remove partially border between a tab and it's linked tabview, as shown in the below image.

[image]

Below is my code to create tabs and tabview.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[


    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 200,
          child: TabBar(
              controller: _controller,
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(

                border: Border(
                    left: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1.0
                    ),
                    right: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1.0
                    ),
                    top: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1.0
                    )
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),

              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Apple"),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Android"),
                  ),
                )
              ]
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),

    AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller.animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: 0,
          child: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 1.0
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: Text("At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium"),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1.0
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco"),
            )
          ] [_controller.animation.value.round()],
        );
      },
    )




  ],
)
```

Below is the code for the tab controller.

```
class ProductDetailState extends State<ProductDetail> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
   TabController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
}


}
```

Comment: Have you set elevation=0 in AppBar?

Comment: I have no app bar for tabs and tabview, I have used as column child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 49,
            left: 10.0,
            right: 10.0,
          ),
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller.animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
              return Transform.rotate(
                angle: 0,
                child: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    child: Text(
                        "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium"),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    child: Text(
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco"),
                  )
                ][_controller.animation.value.round()],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10.0,
                right: 10.0,
              ),
              width: 200,
              height: 50,
              child: TabBar(
                  controller: _controller,
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                      right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                      top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text("Apple"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text("Android"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

[image]
[image]